# Passing parameters with conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Update:**

I have a dropdownlist with seven different options like (date, subject, press, cia, media...) and user will select one of the item from the dropdownlist and click on search button to get the results.

Here is my repository class GetInquiries method which accepts 7 parameters but it will pass only one parameters at a time to the stored procedure and in case of Date (it will pass both from/to)

```
public List<Inquiry> GetInquiries(string fromDate, string toDate, 
                                  string subject, string press,
                                  string cia, string media, 
                                  string status)
```

Here is what I have come up with passing the parameters to `GetInquiries`:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtSubject.Text.Trim()))
 {
     e.Result = reporterRepo.GetInquiries(null,null,txtSubject.Text,null,null,null,null);
 }
 else
 {
     e.Result = reporterRepo.GetInquiries(null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
 }
 else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.fromDate.Text.Trim()))
     e.Result = reporterRepo.GetInquiries(fromDate.Text,null,null,null,null,null,null)
     .......................
     ...................
      ....................
```

I have to continue seven times with (if else if conditions) for all seven parameters.

Is there a way I can do it more clearly and more readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var subjectText = this.txtSubject.Text.Trim();
var dateText = this.fromDate.Text.Trim();

if (subjectText.Length == 0) subjectText = null;
if (dateText .Length == 0) dateText = null;

e.Result = reporterRepo.GetInquiries(dateText ,null,subjectText,
                    null,null,null,null);
```

> > string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtSubject.Text.Trim()))

Note that `this.txtSubject.Text.Trim()` will never be null, and if `this.txtSubject.Text` is null, this will throw an exception.

Comment: i think your code is what i think will fit my needs, but i am not sure i understood by txtSubject.Text is null than thiswill throw an exception can you explain me little bit more?

Comment: if `txtSubject.Text` is null then `txtSubject.Text.Trim()` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Well, depending on your exact situation, this might help:

```
e.Result = reporterRepo.GetInquiries(null, null,
     string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtSubject.Text.Trim()) ? null : txtSubject.Text,
     null, null, null, null);
```

Or if you're using C# 4 and can modify `GetInquiries`, you could possibly make all the parameters optional and use named arguments to specify which one you're actually providing.

Or write methods such as `GetInquiriesByName`, `GetInquiriesBySubject` etc to avoid overloading with clashing parameter types.

EDIT: If there's a dropdown, it sounds like you should be using the value of *that* to determine the appropriate branch to take (i.e. what to search on) and then go from there.

Comment: Jon, but i have to repeat reporterRepo.GetInquiries(....) seven times for seven different parameters.

Comment: @Nisar: It's not clear what you're really trying to achieve, exactly. What should happen if both the subject *and* date fields have been filled in? Do you really want to ignore the date field?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.0 then you take advantge of [optional and default parameters](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/02/optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-in-c-4-and-a-cool-scenario-w-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx). If you're using an earlier framework version, then try creating overloasd of the routine:

```
    public List<Inquiry> GetInquiries(string fromDate, string toDate, 
                                                    string subject, string press,
                                                    string cia, string media) 
    {
// Pass empty string for status.
       return this.GetInquiries(fromDate, toDate, subject, press, cia, media, String.Empty) 
    }

    public List<Inquiry> GetInquiries(string fromDate, string toDate, 
                                                    string subject, string press,
                                                    string cia, string media, 
                                                    string status)
```

Comment: +1 This is the cleanest of the solutions. Might be worth giving an example of how exactly optional/named arguments work though.

Comment: Also note that this is a C# 4.0 feature, .NET/CLR has supported optional parameters for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You reflection to invoke the method GetInquiries with just the n-th argument set.

```
public List<Inquiry> GetInquiries(int numparam, string myparameter)
{
    object[] params = new object[7];
    params[numparam] = myparameter;
    reporterRepo.Gettype().GetMethod("GetInquiries").Invoke(reporterRepo, params);
}
```

I have not tested the code but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Inquiries
{
    private SqlParameter[] _parameters;

    public DateTime FromDate { get{ //return value from parameters array} set{ // add a new parameter to your array } }
    public DateTime ToDate { get{ //return value from parameters array} set{ // add a new parameter to your array } }
    public String Subject { get{ //return value from parameters array} set{ // add a new parameter to your array } }
    public String Press { get{ //return value from parameters array} set{ // add a new parameter to your array } }
    public String Cia { get{ //return value from parameters array} set{ // add a new parameter to your array } }
    public String Media { get{ //return value from parameters array} set{ // add a new parameter to your array } }

    public List<Inquiry> Get()
    {
        // Your dal code using the parameters array
    }
}
```

Then make Inquiries a member level in the formthat's going to get inquiries, and with the changes you do, set the properties appropriately, unless you're only going to do one property at a time then just create the class and toss it each time you use it as:

```
List<Inquiry> myInquires = new Inquiry() { Subject = txtSubject.Text }.Get();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using some sort of a [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern)

So in your example the usage would be

```
var querySpecification = new QuerySpecification();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtSubject.Text.Trim()))
{
     querySpecification = new WhereSubject().Is(txtSubject);
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.fromDate.Text.Trim()))
{
     querySpecification = new WhereFromDate().Is(fromDate);
}
else
{
     querySpecification = new All();
}
e.Result = reporterRepo.GetInquiries(querySpecification);
```

WhereSubject, WhereFromDate and All derives from a common IReportReposSpec.

```
public interface IReportReposSpec
{
      void Is(object value)

      // stored proc translation of the spec
      string Param {get;}
      string DbType {get;}
      string Value {get;}
}
```

The implementation of reporterRepo.GetInquiries could be as such

```
public List<Inquiry> GetInquiries(IReportReposSpec spec)
{
      var cmd = new SqlCommand();
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      // for simplicity i'm going to use a pseudo code from here on
      cmd.AddParam(spec.Param, spec.DbType, spec.Value));

      //...
}
```